# What service quotas could prevent scaling AWS Batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch

I need to run 500 jobs, but they keep getting stuck in `Runnable`. When my jobs *do* start, they run to completion, so there is nothing wrong with their configuration. Maybe it's a us-east-1 *capacity* issue or maybe it's the *service quotas* tied to my account.

What service quotas apply in this scenario? Below are default quotas as candidate suspects. I have submitted requests to increase each of these.

| Service | Quota name | Applied account-level quota value | AWS default quota value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EC2 | Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances | 32 CPUs | 5 |
| EC2 | All Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) Spot Instance Requests | 32 CPUs | 5 |
| EC2 | New Reserved Instances per month | 50 | 20 |
| EC2 | EC2-VPC Elastic IPs | 5 | 5 |

(Batch jobs require a public IP to talk to ECR)

---

**Configuration:**

- AWS Batch - Compute Environment - Max vCPUs: 5000
- AWS Batch - Job Definition - Fargate - vCPUs: 4
- AWS Batch - Job Definition - Fargate - Memory: 8GB
- AWS Batch - Job Definition - Fargate - Ephemeral Storage: 100GB

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The quotas in question were:

- Fargate On-Demand vCPU resource count
- Fargate Spot vCPU resource count

---

As shown by the "utilization" on the right

[image]

> At the time, I had dropped down to 2 vCPU per job in an attempt to  trying to get more instances:
>
> 15 running x 2 vCPU = 30 vCPU quota

It is infuriating that the services enforce quotas, but don't inform the user when they are being enforced.